# How do I remove the cover from my light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I need to replace burned-out light bulbs in a ceiling fixture. I tried to remove the cover of the light fixture and it does not move. After much trying, the whole thing came down. Meaning the fixture body is stuck in the cover and I cannot access the socket. Instead of working on that on top of a ladder, I disconnected the wires. I have the light fixture on my countertop and no amount of pulling, tugging or prying will separate the pieces.

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Any pictures you can provide? Or perhaps there is some sort of model number on the fixture you can give?

Comment: Without a picture or the make/model of the fixture, it's nearly impossible for anybody to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

The rim of the fixture and light globe assembly may have been painted at one time and locked together because of that. It may be necessary to run a sharp utility knife blade around the base of the globe by the rim. This can cut the paint seal and free the globe for removal.